# How do I install numpy in windows successfully

Tags: python, numpy, pip

I have tried installing numpy from my terminal and it is giving me complicated error message. PLease somebody help me, am very new to pythoin and pycharm

Executing `pip3 install numpy command`:

```
C:\Users\Benedict\PycharmProjects\Example1>pip3 install numpy
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.19.2.zip (7.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\benedict\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\benedict\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_
vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\tmpct665suw'
         cwd: C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-install-d1sw4kmw\numpy
    Complete output (200 lines):
    Running from numpy source directory.
    setup.py:470: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
      run_build = parse_setuppy_commands()
    Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pxd.in
    Processing numpy/random\bit_generator.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\mtrand.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pyx.in
    Processing numpy/random\_common.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_generator.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_mt19937.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_pcg64.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_philox.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_sfc64.pyx
    Cythonizing sources
    blas_opt_info:
    blas_mkl_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['c:\\users\\benedict\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\benedict\\appdata\\local\\programs\\
python\\python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    blis_info:
      libraries blis not found in ['c:\\users\\benedict\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\benedict\\appdata\\local\\programs\\py
thon\\python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    openblas_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\users\\benedict\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\benedict\\appdata\\local\\programs
\\python\\python39\\libs']
    get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
    customize GnuFCompiler
    Could not locate executable g77
    Could not locate executable f77
    customize IntelVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable ifort
    Could not locate executable ifl
    customize AbsoftFCompiler
    Could not locate executable f90
    customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable DF
    customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable efl
    customize Gnu95FCompiler
    Could not locate executable gfortran
    Could not locate executable f95
    customize G95FCompiler
    Could not locate executable g95
    customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
    customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
    Could not locate executable efort
    Could not locate executable efc
    customize PGroupFlangCompiler
    Could not locate executable flang
    don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries tatlas not found in ['c:\\users\\benedict\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\benedict\\appdata\\local\\programs\\
python\\python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    atlas_3_10_blas_info:
      libraries satlas not found in ['c:\\users\\benedict\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\benedict\\appdata\\local\\programs\\
python\\python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    atlas_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['c:\\users\\benedict\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\benedict\\appdata\\
local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    atlas_blas_info:
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['c:\\users\\benedict\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\benedict\\appdata\\loca
l\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    accelerate_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-install-d1sw4kmw\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:
        Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
        Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
        A better performance should be easily gained by switching
        Blas library.
      if self._calc_info(blas):
    blas_info:
      libraries blas not found in ['c:\\users\\benedict\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\benedict\\appdata\\local\\programs\\py
thon\\python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-install-d1sw4kmw\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
        the BLAS environment variable.
      if self._calc_info(blas):
    blas_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-install-d1sw4kmw\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
        the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
      if self._calc_info(blas):
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
    lapack_opt_info:
    lapack_mkl_info:
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['c:\\users\\benedict\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\benedict\\appdata\\local\\programs\\
python\\python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    openblas_lapack_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\users\\benedict\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\benedict\\appdata\\local\\programs
\\python\\python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    openblas_clapack_info:
      libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['c:\\users\\benedict\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\benedict\\appdata\\local\\p
rograms\\python\\python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    flame_info:
      libraries flame not found in ['c:\\users\\benedict\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\benedict\\appdata\\local\\programs\\p
ython\\python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    atlas_3_10_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\benedict\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in c:\users\benedict\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\benedict\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in c:\users\benedict\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    atlas_3_10_info:
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\benedict\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in c:\users\benedict\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\benedict\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in c:\users\benedict\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\benedict\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in c:\users\benedict\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\benedict\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in c:\users\benedict\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    atlas_info:
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\benedict\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in c:\users\benedict\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\benedict\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in c:\users\benedict\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    lapack_info:
      libraries lapack not found in ['c:\\users\\benedict\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\benedict\\appdata\\local\\programs\\
python\\python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-install-d1sw4kmw\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1748: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
    lapack_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-install-d1sw4kmw\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1748: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    numpy_linalg_lapack_lite:
      FOUND:
        language = c
        define_macros = [('HAVE_BLAS_ILP64', None), ('BLAS_SYMBOL_SUFFIX', '64_')]
    
    c:\users\benedict\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running dist_info
    running build_src
    build_src
    building py_modules sources
    creating build
    creating build\src.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\src.win-amd64-3.9\numpy
    creating build\src.win-amd64-3.9\numpy\distutils
    building library "npymath" sources
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\benedict\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\benedict\appdata\local\programs\python
\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\tmpct665suw' Check
 the logs for full command output.
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.3; however, version 20.2.4 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'c:\users\benedict\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: Try to debug it step by step by looking at what the error messages say. One of them says "error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/" So I'd suggest you install microsoft visual c++ 14.0 as mentioned via the provided link.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using python 3.9. numpy is not available for it yet.

Question seems to be a duplicate of:

[trying to install numpy in python3.9 and getting error in preparing wheel metadata in windows 10. I did not checked using virtual environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64256526/trying-to-install-numpy-in-python3-9-and-getting-error-in-preparing-wheel-metada)

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Check Python Version
Before you can install NumPy, you need to know which Python version you have. This programming language comes preinstalled on most operating systems (except Windows; you will need to install Python on Windows manually).

Most likely, you have Python 2 or Python 3 installed, or even both versions.

To check whether you have Python 2, run the command:

```
python -V
```

The output should give you a version number.

To see if you have Python 3 on your system, enter the following in the terminal window:

```
python3 -V
```

In the example below, you can see both versions of Python are present.
[image]

Step 3: Download PIP [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py)

Before installing PIP, download the get-pip.py file: get-pip.py on pypa.io.

Download the file to the desired folder in Windows. You can save the file to any location, but remember the path so you can use it later.

Step 4: Installing PIP on Windows
Open the Command Prompt if it isn’t already open. Use the cd command followed by a folder name to navigate to the location of the get-pip.py file. This is the folder you previously used as the download location.

To install PIP type in the following:

python get-pip.py
PIP installation should start. If the file isn’t found, double-check the path to the folder where you saved the file.

You can view the contents of your current directory using the following command:

```
dir
```

The dir command returns a full listing of the contents of a directory.

Step 4: How to Check PIP Version
To check the current version of PIP, type the following command:

```
pip --version
```

This command returns the current version of the platform.

Step 5: Install NumPy
With Pip set up, you can use its command line for installing NumPy.

Install NumPy with Python 2 by typing:

```
pip install numpy
```

Pip downloads the NumPy package and notifies you it has been successfully installed.