# Can't install numpy on python 3.10

Tags: python, version, python-wheel, python-3.10

I'm quite new to machine learning and when I tried to install numpy and this happended Can you guys help me fix this. I'm using python 3.10.0

ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
Failed to build numpy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please provide a bit more detail.  Like what your operating system is and how you're installing numpy as well as the full error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [trying to install numpy in python3.9 and getting error in preparing wheel metadata in windows 10. I did not checked using virtual environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64256526/trying-to-install-numpy-in-python3-9-and-getting-error-in-preparing-wheel-metada)

Comment: This is asked every new version. I wish it were more Google-searchable [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64256526/913098)

Answer (score 9):

I faced the same issue, I have a macos high sierra with python 3.10 and I have the same error while installing numpy in pip.
I managed to solve the problem by installing not the newest **numpy 1.22.2** in pip. I install version **1.22.1**.

Command:

```
pip install numpy==1.22.1
```

Answer (score 5):

`Numpy` has not yet released a precompiled wheel for Python 3.10. What you can do, is downgrade to python 3.9. If you don't want to do this, you can try the unofficial wheels available [here](http://%20https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy).

These are the important ones you should look for:

- `numpy‑1.21.2+mkl‑cp310‑cp310‑win_amd64.whl`
- `numpy‑1.21.2+mkl‑cp310‑cp310‑win32.whl`

(Choose based on your OS architecture)

Then download the file, go to your downloads folder, and run `pip install "<your_filename_choice>.whl")`.

You could also just use the `pipwin` module.
Do this:

```
pip install pipwin
```

and then

```
pipwin install numpy
```

Comment: These unofficial binaries are only for Windows.

Comment: Install also fails for me, with a similar error, under Python3.9...

Answer (score 1):

Note that wheels have been available for Python 3.10 since 5th November, see:

https://pypi.org/project/numpy/#files

specifically, I can see Python wheels for labelled as version `cp310` (i.e. CPython 3.10) for Linux, Mac and Windows.